# Highest value since - finding the interval in R

Tags: r, lag, runner

I'm working right now at Forex project and I found a problem on my way. I'm trying to find when was the last time when current value was this high or this low.

At the beginning I was trying to do that this way:

```
length(c(1:10)) - max(which(c(1:10) <= 6))
```

i.e. if we consider vector `c(1:10,6)` the output of the function above would be 4. Which would mean that 6 is the highest value since 4 intervals.

So my goal now was to implement above function into `dplyr::mutate` method. That's where things got out of hand... With the `runner` function from `runner` package I was able to create tibble with values and their lags:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 2
   value `runner(value, lag = 1)`
   <dbl> <list>                  
 1     9 <dbl [0]>               
 2     7 <dbl [1]>               
 3     4 <dbl [2]>               
 4     1 <dbl [3]>               
 5     5 <dbl [4]>               
 6     2 <dbl [5]>               
 7     5 <dbl [6]>               
 8     4 <dbl [7]>               
 9     1 <dbl [8]>               
10     6 <dbl [9]>               
11     6 <dbl [10]>
```

But then no matter what I have tried I can't relate value number at current list to a runner column. I was trying things like `purrr:map` or `sapply` but is still would refer to whole column. I also trying to implement `dplyr::rowWise` but it didn't help me either.

I feel like I am going around the solution and that it can clearly be done easily. If there is some magic package that would help me to solve my issue quickly I would be more than thankful for help. But I would still like to know if there is a way to relate in that kind of situation to the current row value instead of whole column.

I was also trying to close this into one tidy user made function so that would be another plus if you could point me in that direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution thanks to the @allan-cameron 's answer:

```
last_below <- function(x) {
  sapply(
    seq(x), 
    function(i) {
      (i - tail(which(x[0:(i-1)] <= x[i]),1))[1]
    }
  )
}
```

By calling:

```
a %>% 
  mutate(b = last_below(value))
```

I get the output:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 2
   value     b
   <dbl> <int>
 1     9    NA
 2     7    NA
 3     4    NA
 4     1    NA
 5     5     1
 6     2     2
 7     5     1
 8     4     2
 9     1     5
10     6     1
11     6     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your looking for something like this?

```r
last_below <- function(x)
{
  sapply(seq(x), function(i) {
    y <- i - rev(which(x[i] >= cummax(x)))[1]
    if(y < 0) 0 else y
  })
}
```

So you can do

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(x = c(1:10, 6, 4, 5, 2))
df %>% mutate(y = last_below(x))
#>     x  y
#> 1   1  0
#> 2   2  0
#> 3   3  0
#> 4   4  0
#> 5   5  0
#> 6   6  0
#> 7   7  0
#> 8   8  0
#> 9   9  0
#> 10 10  0
#> 11  6  5
#> 12  4  8
#> 13  5  8
#> 14  2 12
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Allan, it looks promising but after implementing it to the sampled vector I am getting error that there is no value where T/F value should be. I can not copy direct error massage unless you are fluent in Polish :)

Comment: @Radbys are there NA values in the vector?

Comment: Nope, it's a tibble with one column with values: 9, 7, 4, 1, 5, 2, 5, 4, 1, 6, 6

Comment: @Radbys Please edit your question to _show the desired output_ given a data frame with the vector in your comment.

Comment: IMO `Created on [...] by the reprex package (v0.3.0)` is just clutter.

Comment: @sindri_baldur yes, I know. I mostly just forget to remove it after I have used reprex. On the odd occasion I think it's helpful as a marker to say "this code will actually produce this result", but most of the time it doesn't add anything.

Answer (score 0):

it can be definitely done with `runner`.
Be aware that `function(x)` in `runner` is evaluated for each cumulation - try `runner(vec)` to see the result (list). Imagine that each element of this list is one step, and `function(x)` is executed for each step.

Imagine that for one step (for example 10'th) you need to find how many observation before current had matched condition.

```r
library(runner)
set.seed(1)

# dummy data
x <- round(cumsum(rnorm(10)))

current_idx <- 10
current_x <- x[current_idx]
up_to_current <- x[-current_idx]
current_idx - which(up_to_current == current_x)
# [1] 2 5
```

Above code can be body of the `function(x)` - how "far ago" were matching condition before current

```r
runner(
  vec,
  function(x) {
    # current index
    current_idx <- length(x)
    
    # current value
    current_x <- x[current_idx]
    
    # values up to current
    up_to_current <- x[-current_idx]
        
    # how many observations since last condition matching 
    current_idx - which(up_to_current == current_x)       
  }  
)
```

Above returns a list, because output of the `function(x)` varies in length. If it returns single value - it will return a vector.

---

P.S. to find the index of matching condition **after** current observation you will need to include `rev(vec)` and play around with indices difference.

Enjoy!